# Selected elements in Forge Viewer are incorrectly displayed in 2D views on mobile/tablet

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Found some strange behavior when selecting elements in 2d views/sheets on iPad/iPhone.

1. Selected elements are not shown / only partly shown
2. Selected elements are incorrectly shown (wrong position)
3. Selecting elements leads to different element being selected. (When selecting a e.g a Wall, a completely different Wall is highlighted - could also be due to 2.)

**Example 1:**

In both images, the same element(slab) is selected, on iPad (top), a completely different area is marked in the viewer. On PC (bottom), the correct Element is highlighted in the viewer. (images here are blurred due to client's copyright). DbId is the same!

[image: example 1 - selection of slab on iPad]
[image: example 1 - selection of slab on PC]

**Example 2:**

Here, another element is selected on iPad(top) and PC(bottom) in a different model. The top image shows the ipad screen after selecting the element. As a result, the element is highlighted in the list on the right side. However, the element is not highlighted in the viewer. On PC(bottom), everything works as expected and the element is highlighted.

[image: example 2 - selection of slab on iPad]
[image]

In both examples, model and view as well as dbId of selection in the viewer are the same, respectively.
Problem occurred on Safari and Chrome, on iPad(iOS 12 and iPadOS 13) and iPhone(iOS 13).

Forge Viewer Events triggered because of selecting elements are the same on iPad and PC.

When simulating iPad on PC with Chrome (+touch events), the problem does NOT exist.

Both examples are Revit Models, with multiple 3d and 2d views published.

Anyone else has this problem as well?
Any idea how to fix this? Or is this a viewer bug?
Thanks for helping out :)

Comment: pls upload the original drawing (to dropbox, gdrive, wetransfer etc) and send the link over to forge.help@autodesk.com so we can look into this. tks!

Comment: Forgot to mention that the 2d views originate from Revit. So its a Revit File, with multiple 3d and 2d Views published. 3d views of the same model within the browser do NOT have the problem described above. Should I upload and send link to revit model? @BryanHuang